# Python time.sleep only for one part of script

Tags: refresh, lcd

I have sript for 3 lcd display on my rassbery pi, and have problem with
time sleep function.
I would like to have a pause only for  screen 3 ( after 10s show different data ), and the other LCD should run normaly, without time sleep - pause

example :

```
# LCD1
mylcd1.lcd_display_string("TEMP1:",1,0) 
mylcd1.lcd_display_string(str(temp1),1,5) 
mylcd1.lcd_display_string ("%s" %time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),3, 0)

# LCD2
mylcd2.lcd_display_string("TEMP2:",1,0)
mylcd2.lcd_display_string(str(temp2),1,5)

# LCD3
mylcd3.lcd_clear()   
mylcd3.lcd_display_string("TEMP3:",1,0)
mylcd3.lcd_display_string(str(temp3),1,5)

time.sleep(10)
mylcd3.lcd_clear()
mylcd3.lcd_display_string("DIM:",1,0) 
mylcd3.lcd_display_string(str(dp1),1,4)
```

In this example is problem time in LCD1, It does not run smoothly, it has to wait 10s, and temperature data on LCD 1 and LCD 2 it must be refreshed in real time without delay....

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

I would say an easy way to go about this is have your LCD's that need to be updated running in a loop, and have a variable that is keeping track of the time.

Then within your loop have an if statement checking if the time % 10 seconds == 0 then run the refresh of the Screen that needs the delay.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to write .... the compete code is already in loop...
I want add time.sleep only for part for LCD3 ...
LCD3 change data every 10 sec.